# Как задать вращение блокам с разной скоростью?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сверху прикрепил библиотеку, сама функция вращения в конце. может быть есть способ попроще без дополнительных библиотек кроме jquery?

Ниже сам пример кода, обратился как бы к разным переменным но вращаются они почему то одинаково.

```js
//библиотека jquery rotate
(function(g) {
  for (var d, j = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].style, h = "transformProperty WebkitTransform OTransform msTransform MozTransform".split(" "), e = 0; e < h.length; e++) j[h[e]] !== void 0 && (d = h[e]);
  var i = "v" == "\v";
  jQuery.fn.extend({
    ImageRotate: function(a) {
      if (!this.Wilq32 || !this.Wilq32.PhotoEffect) return a = g.extend(!0, {}, a), (new Wilq32.PhotoEffect(this.get(0), a))._rootObj
    },
    rotate: function(a) {
      if (!(this.length === 0 || typeof a == "undefined")) {
        typeof a == "number" && (a = {
          angle: a
        });
        for (var c = [], b = 0, d = this.length; b < d; b++) {
          var f = this.get(b);
          typeof f.Wilq32 == "undefined" ? c.push(g(g(f).ImageRotate(a))) : f.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._handleRotation(a)
        }
        return c
      }
    }
  });
  Wilq32 = window.Wilq32 || {};
  Wilq32.PhotoEffect = function() {
    return d ? function(a, c) {
      a.Wilq32 = {
        PhotoEffect: this
      };
      this._img = this._rootObj = this._eventObj = a;
      this._handleRotation(c)
    } : function(a, c) {
      this._img = a;
      this._rootObj = document.createElement("span");
      this._rootObj.style.display = "inline-block";
      this._rootObj.Wilq32 = {
        PhotoEffect: this
      };
      a.parentNode.insertBefore(this._rootObj,
        a);
      if (a.complete) this._Loader(c);
      else {
        var b = this;
        jQuery(this._img).bind("load", function() {
          b._Loader(c)
        })
      }
    }
  }();
  Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype = {
    _setupParameters: function(a) {
      this._parameters = this._parameters || {};
      if (typeof this._angle !== "number") this._angle = 0;
      if (typeof a.angle === "number") this._angle = a.angle;
      this._parameters.animateTo = typeof a.animateTo === "number" ? a.animateTo : this._angle;
      this._parameters.easing = a.easing || this._parameters.easing || function(a, b, d, f, e) {
        return -f * ((b = b / e - 1) * b * b * b - 1) + d
      };
      this._parameters.duration =
        a.duration || this._parameters.duration || 1E3;
      this._parameters.callback = a.callback || this._parameters.callback || function() {};
      a.bind && a.bind != this._parameters.bind && this._BindEvents(a.bind)
    },
    _handleRotation: function(a) {
      this._setupParameters(a);
      this._angle == this._parameters.animateTo ? this._rotate(this._angle) : this._animateStart()
    },
    _BindEvents: function(a) {
      if (a && this._eventObj) {
        if (this._parameters.bind) {
          var c = this._parameters.bind,
            b;
          for (b in c) c.hasOwnProperty(b) && jQuery(this._eventObj).unbind(b, c[b])
        }
        this._parameters.bind =
          a;
        for (b in a) a.hasOwnProperty(b) && jQuery(this._eventObj).bind(b, a[b])
      }
    },
    _Loader: function() {
      return i ? function(a) {
        var c = this._img.width,
          b = this._img.height;
        this._img.parentNode.removeChild(this._img);
        this._vimage = this.createVMLNode("image");
        this._vimage.src = this._img.src;
        this._vimage.style.height = b + "px";
        this._vimage.style.width = c + "px";
        this._vimage.style.position = "absolute";
        this._vimage.style.top = "0px";
        this._vimage.style.left = "0px";
        this._container = this.createVMLNode("group");
        this._container.style.width =
          c;
        this._container.style.height = b;
        this._container.style.position = "absolute";
        this._container.setAttribute("coordsize", c - 1 + "," + (b - 1));
        this._container.appendChild(this._vimage);
        this._rootObj.appendChild(this._container);
        this._rootObj.style.position = "relative";
        this._rootObj.style.width = c + "px";
        this._rootObj.style.height = b + "px";
        this._rootObj.setAttribute("id", this._img.getAttribute("id"));
        this._rootObj.className = this._img.className;
        this._eventObj = this._rootObj;
        this._handleRotation(a)
      } : function(a) {
        this._rootObj.setAttribute("id",
          this._img.getAttribute("id"));
        this._rootObj.className = this._img.className;
        this._width = this._img.width;
        this._height = this._img.height;
        this._widthHalf = this._width / 2;
        this._heightHalf = this._height / 2;
        var c = Math.sqrt(this._height * this._height + this._width * this._width);
        this._widthAdd = c - this._width;
        this._heightAdd = c - this._height;
        this._widthAddHalf = this._widthAdd / 2;
        this._heightAddHalf = this._heightAdd / 2;
        this._img.parentNode.removeChild(this._img);
        this._aspectW = (parseInt(this._img.style.width, 10) || this._width) /
          this._img.width;
        this._aspectH = (parseInt(this._img.style.height, 10) || this._height) / this._img.height;
        this._canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        this._canvas.setAttribute("width", this._width);
        this._canvas.style.position = "relative";
        this._canvas.style.left = -this._widthAddHalf + "px";
        this._canvas.style.top = -this._heightAddHalf + "px";
        this._canvas.Wilq32 = this._rootObj.Wilq32;
        this._rootObj.appendChild(this._canvas);
        this._rootObj.style.width = this._width + "px";
        this._rootObj.style.height = this._height + "px";
        this._eventObj =
          this._canvas;
        this._cnv = this._canvas.getContext("2d");
        this._handleRotation(a)
      }
    }(),
    _animateStart: function() {
      this._timer && clearTimeout(this._timer);
      this._animateStartTime = +new Date;
      this._animateStartAngle = this._angle;
      this._animate()
    },
    _animate: function() {
      var a = +new Date,
        c = a - this._animateStartTime > this._parameters.duration;
      if (c && !this._parameters.animatedGif) clearTimeout(this._timer);
      else {
        (this._canvas || this._vimage || this._img) && this._rotate(~~(this._parameters.easing(0, a - this._animateStartTime, this._animateStartAngle,
          this._parameters.animateTo - this._animateStartAngle, this._parameters.duration) * 10) / 10);
        var b = this;
        this._timer = setTimeout(function() {
          b._animate.call(b)
        }, 10)
      }
      if (this._parameters.callback && c) this._angle = this._parameters.animateTo, this._rotate(this._angle), this._parameters.callback.call(this._rootObj)
    },
    _rotate: function() {
      var a = Math.PI / 180;
      return i ? function(a) {
        this._angle = a;
        this._container.style.rotation = a % 360 + "deg"
      } : d ? function(a) {
        this._angle = a;
        this._img.style[d] = "rotate(" + a % 360 + "deg)"
      } : function(c) {
        this._angle =
          c;
        c = c % 360 * a;
        this._canvas.width = this._width + this._widthAdd;
        this._canvas.height = this._height + this._heightAdd;
        this._cnv.translate(this._widthAddHalf, this._heightAddHalf);
        this._cnv.translate(this._widthHalf, this._heightHalf);
        this._cnv.rotate(c);
        this._cnv.translate(-this._widthHalf, -this._heightHalf);
        this._cnv.scale(this._aspectW, this._aspectH);
        this._cnv.drawImage(this._img, 0, 0)
      }
    }()
  };
  if (i) Wilq32.PhotoEffect.prototype.createVMLNode = function() {
    document.createStyleSheet().addRule(".rvml", "behavior:url(#default#VML)");
    try {
      return !document.namespaces.rvml && document.namespaces.add("rvml", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"),
        function(a) {
          return document.createElement("<rvml:" + a + ' class="rvml">')
        }
    } catch (a) {
      return function(a) {
        return document.createElement("<" + a + ' xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.com:vml" class="rvml">')
      }
    }
  }()
})(jQuery);

// сама функция:

var angle = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  angle += 1;
  jQuery(".views-row-1 .field-name-border").rotate(angle);
}, 50);

setInterval(function() {
  angle += 1;
  jQuery(".views-row-2 .field-name-border").rotate(angle);
}, 12);
```

```css
.field-name-border {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.views-row-1,
.views-row-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="views-row-1">
  <div class="field-name-border"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="views-row-2">
  <div class="field-name-border"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      angle += 1;
      jQuery(".views-row-1 .field-name-border").css('transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)');
    }, 50);
    
    setInterval(function() {
      angle += 1;
      jQuery(".views-row-2 .field-name-border").css('transform', 'rotate('+angle+'deg)');
    }, 12);
```

```css
.field-name-border {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.views-row-1,
.views-row-2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="views-row-1">
  <div class="field-name-border"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="views-row-2">
  <div class="field-name-border"></div>
</div>
</div>
```